# Obter links externos com cURL PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho este código que me retorna a página do Google.

```
<?php

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, [
    CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.google.com.br',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
]);
$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);

echo $response;
```

Porém, ele não me trás os links externos como imagem entre outros. Repare que, ao em vez dele me trazer google.com/... ele trás o nome do meu *vHOST* *viperfollowdev.com*, veja a imagem a baixo para entender.

Existe alguma maneira de corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu segundo exemplo foi:

```
<?php

$request = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($request, array(
    CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://www.instagram.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
));

$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);

$response = str_replace('/static/bundles/', 'https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/', $response);
$response = str_replace('/static/images/', 'https://www.instagram.com/static/images/', $response);
$response = str_replace('/data/manifest.json', 'https://www.instagram.com/data/manifest.json', $response);

echo $response;
```

Está pegando porém não mostra ainda na minha página. Passei a **url** inteira mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sobre o erro

Isso ocorre pois a Google não utiliza o link completo dos arquivos nos atributos `src`, `srcset` etc. Ao invés disso, ela utiliza apenas o `path` do arquivo: Ex: `/path/to/image.png`

Com isso o navegador sempre vai procurar essas imagens no site acessado, no seu caso, `http://viperfollowdev.com`.

### Soluções

Para corrigir isso, basta adicionar o código abaixo ao imprimir a variável `$response`.

```
echo '<base href="https://www.google.com.br/" />';
```

Porém essa solução não funcionará em todos os casos. Quando você já tem definido a url base (como no código acima) em seu `html`, o navegador ignorará a nova "url de base".

Nesse caso, resta apenas utilizar a `regex` para solucionar seu caso *(ou ao menos parte dele)*.

**Regex**

```
(src=|href=|srcset=|url)('|"|\()(\/.*?)('|"|\))
```

A `regex` acima irá capturar todos os valores dos atributos `src`, `srcset`, `href` e `url`. Esse último para `css`.

Agora basta utilizar a função [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php) para substituir os valores.

**Exemplo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <base href="https://www.bing.com.br/" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $url = "https://www.google.com.br";

            $request = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt_array($request, [
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            ]);
            $response = curl_exec($request);
            curl_close($request);

            echo preg_replace("/(src=|href=|srcset=|url)('|\"|\()(\/.*?)('|\"|\))/", "$1$2{$url}$3$4", $response);

        ?>

        <script src="/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> A `regex` pode variar de site para site. A depender do que você queira alterar, é necessário customizar a `regex` e deixa-lo mais completo, porém o principio é o mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, olha meu segundo exemplo na minha pergunta quase parecido, só que o seu mais organizado.

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro caso o que acontece é que você obteve o código html do request e os recursos são declarados para caminhos virtuais que não existem na sua aplicação. Algo que já você deve ter percebido por fazer o replace em sua segunda tentantiva. Mas existem outras validações e procedimentos que são executadas no host e impedem você de apresentar o conteúdo deles. (Sessões, Tokens, Headers e etc.)

Aconselho que se você quer consumir ou exibir o conteúdo de outros sites e serviços, deve se restringir à suas APIs, regras e termo de uso.

Dê uma olhada em [Google API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) e [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), talvez o que você busca fazer é até suportado pelas duas plataformas.

Comment: Concordo, "deve se restringir à suas APIs, regras e termo de uso.", é pra estudos veja que, na primeira tentativa foi com o google.